# How to add "Initiate checkout" Facebook pixel Standard events on Magento Proceed to checkout?

Tags: magento-1.7, onepage-checkout, facebook, ecommerce-tracking

**Magento Version 1.7**

I want to add the **Facebook pixel** `InitiateCheckout` standard events on my website Proceed To Checkout button click.

I tried to add a JavaScript function on **link.phtml**(\app\design\frontend\default\default\template\checkout\onepage) and remove the `onclick="window.location='<?php echo $this->getCheckoutUrl() ?>';">` and call this window location in the function **track_fbq()**

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Proceed to Checkout') ?>" class="button btn-proceed-checkout btn-checkout<?php if ($this->isDisabled()):?> no-checkout<?php endif; ?>"<?php if ($this->isDisabled()):?> disabled="disabled"<?php endif; ?> onclick="track_fbq()"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Proceed to Checkout') ?></span></span></button>
```

My JavaScript function is below.

```
<script>
  function track_fbq(){

    window.location="<?php echo $this->getCheckoutUrl() ?>";
    fbq('track', 'InitiateCheckout');
  }
</script>
<noscript>
<img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
           src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=1677576565828693&ev=InitiateCheckout&value=<?php echo Value ?>&currency=<?php echo $currency ?>&noscript=1"
    />
</noscript>
```

My checkout is redirect to the checkout page and i can complete the purchase.

My question is, **Is my approach is correct?** If my method is not correct can you please help me to do this task.This is not a question that ask about Facebook tracking.
Thank you.

Comment: This will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23244945/facebook-conversion-tracking-in-magento

Comment: Thank you @PrashantValanda.I want to understand that called the checkout url in the javascript file is correct or not?

Comment: You can add this code to head.phtml file.

Comment: I want to pass the value to  fbq('track', 'InitiateCheckout');.How can i add the value then?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add code to app/design/frontend/Your-Package/Your-Theme/template/page/html/head.phtml

```
<?php if(Mage::getURL('checkout/onepage') == Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl()){ ?>

<script>
    fbq('track', 'InitiateCheckout');
</script>
<noscript>
<img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
           src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=1677576565828693&ev=InitiateCheckout&value=<?php echo Value ?>&currency=<?php echo $currency ?>&noscript=1"
    />
</noscript>

<?php } ?>
```

Hope it will helpful to you.

Comment: how to get the value of the order here?

Comment: Do you mean cart grand total?

Comment: yes the grand total of the order or else simply the order details?In the link.phtml i can get the value using $checkoutDataArr = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getData();

Comment: Yes using above code you get all detail of cart. Here is for grandtotal $total = $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal();

Comment: Can  use the above code in head.phtml rather than link.phtml.I only want to execute the facebook tracking code each and every time customer click the proceed to checkout button.

Comment: Yes you can use this code in head.phtml

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36950/discussion-between-mujas-and-prashant-valanda).